# How I can handle a multi-projects support in Idea in GIT support context?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, playframework, multi-project

I have several projects which are under git repositories. All projects have its own GIT-url in the repository.

I try to import them to IntelliJ-idea: it works/resolves more or less well but there is a problem with git integration for idea. When I import all these projects as modules (using play idealize) and then open them, I have only one project/module under git.

I.e. when I change some code in one-project, it shows changes (in Changes tab), but when I change a piece of code in the second-project it does not show anything. I guess I could somehow change the Root Of Content for GIT for a particular project which is the current one for being integrated with git? But I did not find this option yet.

So how can I handle this multi-projects feature in idea inside GIT support context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes sure all module directories are listed in `Settings` | `Version Control` and are mapped to Git.